# Getting Error "Global name must be unique" when run Munit

Tags: mule4, munit

I am getting below error when i try to run the munits. I am using Anypoint studio 7.4.2 and mUnit version 2.2.4.

"Two configuration elements have been defined with the same global name. Global name must be unique. Clashing components are sub-flow and sub-flow"

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you don't have multiple sub-flow components with the same doc:name defined. That is the cause of the error.